# How to make sure input into a char isn't too long?

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make sure the user enters only **one** charcter.
Like if the input is "ab", the code will throw an exception.

```
char ch = ' ';
std::cin >> ch;

// I'm stuck here
```

Comment: Enter a string and check the size?

Comment: Input a whole `std::string`, and parse that one for value extraction and validation.

Comment: Also, why do you want to throw an exception on someone typing in long input?  IMO that is overkill.  Just assign the first character of the inputted string, with some sort of prompt saying you are only taking the first character.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I do it for school, that's what they have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter the input into an entire string, and process just the first character:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    char ch = ' ';
    if ( input.size() > 1 )
    {
       // Entered more than 1 character
    }
    else
       ch = input[0];
}
```